# Calculating the equilibria of a system of two coupled oscillators?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

**Equations:**
I have the following system of ODEs:

```
Phi1'[t]=omega1-a*Sin[Phi1[t]-Phi2[t]];
Phi2'[t]=-omega1-a*Sin[Phi2[t]-Phi1[t]];
```

**Question:**
Is there a straightforward way of using Mathematica to calculate the equilibria of this system and determine their stability?

**Comments:**
If this system did not entail the sine terms, I would simply set the equations equal to zero, solve for the equilibria, and determine the conditions under which the equilibria satisfy the Routh-Hurwitz criterion. But I am not sure how to deal with the sine terms. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a conserved quantity since `Phi1'[t]+Phi2'[t]==0`. You can "algebraicize" by trig expanding and making everything a polynomial in sines and cosines of the phis. Then augment with trig identities (or use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html)). I do the former below. Note that I handle the conservation also using a trig, and introducing a new constant.

```
exprs0 = {omega1 - a*Sin[phi1 - phi2], -omega1 - a*Sin[phi2 - phi1], 
   Cos[phi1 + phi2] - c};
exprs1 = TrigExpand[exprs0];
params = {omega1, a, c};
svars = Union[Cases[exprs1, Sin[a_], Infinity]];
cvars = Union[Cases[exprs1, Cos[a_], Infinity]];
augment = Map[#^2 + Cos[#[[1]]]^2 - 1 &, svars];
trigrule = {Cos -> cos, Sin -> sin};
exprs = Join[exprs1, augment] /. trigrule
tvars = Complement[Variables[exprs], params]

(* {omega1 - a cos[phi2] sin[phi1] + a cos[phi1] sin[phi2], -omega1 + 
  a cos[phi2] sin[phi1] - a cos[phi1] sin[phi2], -c + 
  cos[phi1] cos[phi2] - sin[phi1] sin[phi2], -1 + cos[phi1]^2 + 
  sin[phi1]^2, -1 + cos[phi2]^2 + sin[phi2]^2}

{cos[phi1], cos[phi2], sin[phi1], sin[phi2]} *)
```

I solve with a particular set of parameter values to find those trig values. The step of applying `ArcSin` to the sines is not necessarily correct since we are dealing with a multivalued inverse.

```
solns = SolveValues[(exprs == 0) /. Thread[params -> {1, 2, 1}], 
   tvars];
sines = solns[[All, 3 ;; 4]];
Map[ArcSin, sines, {2}] // N

(* Out[446]= {{-0.261799, 0.261799}, {0.261799, -0.261799}, {-1.309, 
  1.309}, {1.309, -1.309}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`DSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html).

Here, I'm using initial conditions and some values for `omega1` and `a` to plot a solution, but [`DSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolveValue.html) can indeed handle the fully-symbolic case too:

```mathematica
eqs = {
   Phi1'[t] == omega1 - a*Sin[Phi1[t] - Phi2[t]], 
   Phi2'[t] == -omega1 - a*Sin[Phi2[t] - Phi1[t]]
   };

ics = {Phi1[0] == 1, Phi2[0] == 0};

sols[t_] = DSolveValue[{eqs, ics}, {Phi1[t], Phi2[t]}, t]
Plot[Evaluate[sols[t] /. {omega1 -> 1, a -> 2}], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am going to give this a try.

Comment: Also, if by "equilibria" you mean the steady-state behavior - you can perhaps look at `Limit` or `Asymptotic`, e.g. `Asymptotic[sols[t] /. {omega1 -> 1, a -> 2}, t -> \[Infinity]]`

Comment: After further analysis, I found that the Limit function does work for this! Thank you! Do you by any chance know how one could determine whether the equilibrium/asymptote is stable? Would the Routh-Hurwitz criterion suffice for this?